# Input string not in correct format SPSite

Tags: c#, sharepoint, wss-2.0

i am using WSS 2.0 with sharepoint portal server 2003.
i am making web application in vs 2008 which opens sharepoint site created in portal server.

when i am passing site address to SPSite it gives me error. "Input String not in Correct format"

here is my code

```
string site_Str= "http://<serverName>:<PortNumber>/sites/<TopLevelSite>";
SPSite site=new SPSite(site_Str); // here it gives error
```

and here is stack trace

```
"   at Microsoft.SharePoint.i.a(Boolean A_0, String A_1, Guid A_2, Int32& A_3)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.j()\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.a(String A_0, SPVirtualServer A_1, a A_2, Int32 A_3)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(String strUrl)\r\n   at testRoundLink._Default.GetJavaScript() in E:\\resarch\\testRoundLink\\testRoundLink\\Default.aspx.cs:line 46\r\n   at testRoundLink._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\\resarch\\testRoundLink\\testRoundLink\\Default.aspx.cs:line 19\r\n   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)\r\n   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)\r\n   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)\r\n   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()\r\n   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)"
```

How can i resolve this.

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us a runtime value of that url string with servername portnumber and site exploded?

Comment: "http://spsserver:1600/sites/Test%20Portal" Test Portal is created and i can browse it from browser.

Comment: 1 thing i noticed today is that, when i run above code from console application, it runs perfectly. But when i try to run same code in website built in vs 2005, it gives me above mentioned error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
string site_Str= "http://<serverName>:<PortNumber>";
SPSite site=new SPSite(site_Str);
```